# How to count time in chisel with iotesters?

Tags: hdl, chisel

Is there a way to get the step value in iotesters ?
Currently I'm using a var counter but I'm sure there is a better way :

```scala
class MyTest (dut: MyModule) extends PeekPokeTester(dut) {
  var timeCounter = 0
  for(i <- 0 to 10) {
    step(1)
    timeCounter = timeCounter + 1
  }
  println("Step value is " + timeCounter)
```

Is there a `getStepValue()` like function to get that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this using the [(presently undocumented) method `t`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/chisel-testers/SNAPSHOT/chisel3/iotesters/PeekPokeTester.html#t:Long).

There's an internal [var `simTime` that is tracking time](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel-testers/blob/master/src/main/scala/chisel3/iotesters/PeekPokeTester.scala#L82). This is automatically incremented on a `step` (just like how you're doing it). The method `t` lets you query the query its value.

Comment: I Can try to document it.